# Summing columns based on unique values in multiple columns

Tags: mysql

If I have a database of first names and annual incomes for two years as enumerated columns (I know this is poor database design but I don't have the liberty to change it at the moment). For example:

Name_2000, Name_2010, Income_2000, Income_2010

How can I construct a query to return all the unique names in both name columns in the first result column. The second result column should be the sum of all incomes for that name for 2000. The third should be the sum of all incomes for that name for 2010.

Obviously, in this example a person (record) may change names between years or not have a name in either year too.

Can I do this in a single query? The ability to filter by a certain subset of names would also be handy..

Comment: Can you show some sample data and the result you're trying to get? I specifically want to understand how you want to address name changes.

Comment: The same record would simply have different name in Name_2010 vs Name_2000.

Comment: So you'd like to have two rows in the result, one for the 2000 name with a `null` for the 2010 income and one for the 2010 name with `null` in the 2000 income?

Comment: No. I just want one row per unique name in both years. The sums should be the cumulative total for all names matching that row for that year. There would only be a 0 if that name had no occurrences for that year if you know what i mean...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a sub query that unions 2 results together, one for each set of names and incomes, but each returning a dummy 0 for the income for the other year.

Something like this:-

```
SELECT aname, SUM(aincome2000), SUM(aincome2010)
FROM
(
    SELECT Name_2000 AS aname, Income_2000 AS aincome2000, 0 AS aincome2010
    FROM sometable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Name_2010 AS aname, 0 AS aincome2000, Income_2010 AS aincome2010
    FROM sometable
) sub1
GROUP BY aname
```

Comment: Holy cow. It works. Not fast but it should get me over the line. Thanks. I also added a 'WHERE char_length(aname) > 1' to remove the row with zeros and a blank aname

Comment: Depending on indexes it could be speeded up. You could add your required WHERE clause to both the unioned sub queries (where they could possibly use an index), and similarly you could do the SUM in each of the sub queries.